# No project found with name 'undefined' Botkit + rasa_NLU

Tags: javascript, python, botkit, rasa-nlu

I am trying to deploy on Slack a chatbot that I have developed with rasa_nlu and that I can run locally on my computer by launching a python script on a Ubuntu shell. So I am trying to use botkit.

I am trying to follow this tutorial :

https://github.com/sohlex/botkit-rasa

I have managed to connect to Slack (basically the bot that I have created on Slack appears as online). Now when I talk to the bot I get the following error message on my Ubuntu shell :

[image]

I guess it’s all about where (in what folder) I enter the command (or what I enter as project path) :

```
$ python -m rasa_nlu.server --path projects
```

Do you have any insight for this ?

Thank you for the help,

Best,

Comment: What's the request look like coming from Slack? What version of Rasa are you running? It look like the POST to the Rasa api which should be `project=my_project` is coming from slack as `project=undefined`.

Comment: Caleb,

Thank you very much for your answer. There are indeed these lines of code in the main file (bot.js):

    const rasa = require('../example/middleware-rasa')({
    rasa_uri: 'http://localhost:5000',
    rasa_project: undefined
    })

Now I havre tired to change it to the name of my project but it doesn't work any better...

I am using rasa_nlu 12.2 and rasa_core 0.9.0a2.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and the below code fixed it for me.

```
var rasa = require('botkit-rasa')(
                       {rasa_uri: 'http://localhost:5000', rasa_project: 'default'});
```